# Disable Jupyter Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: html, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

One of my Jupyter notebooks uses an html `<input>` tag that expects typed user input, but whenever I type in the text box, command mode keyboard shortcuts activate.

Is it possible to turn off keyboard shortcuts for a single cell or notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Jupyter.keyboard_manager.disable()` to disable the shortcuts temporarily, and use `Jupyter.keyboard_manager.enable()` to activate again.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just be sure to add the JS magics (%%javascript) prior to calling Jupyter.keyboard_manager.disable()

Comment: Can also be bound to onfocusin event of (parent) element that contains html input:

htmlContainer.onfocusin = () => Jupyter.keyboard_manager.disable();

Comment: unfortunately renaming the notebook seems to re-enable the keyboard_manager

Comment: This doesn't work consistently inside widgets. Is there not a simple property I can set on a text entry widget that turns off shortcuts while I'm typing in it? I don't understand why this doesn't already happen by default.

Comment: I used this with jquery's focus and blur functions for a custom textarea input (inside an extension) and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the current 'Customize keymaps' docuemntation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/keymaps.html), this can now be done using the `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` file more simply than [hlin117](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2014591/hlin117)'s answer:

> For example, to unbind the shortcut to split a cell at the position of the cursor (Ctrl-Shift-Minus)use the following:

```
// file ~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json
{
  "keys": {
    "edit": {
      "unbind": [
        "Ctrl-Shift-Minus"
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could copy paste this line into your custom.js:

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    ...
    // Starting from this line, replace 'Shift-k' with whatever 
    // shortcut you're trying to remove.
    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut('Shift-k')
    ...
});
```

Or whatever shortcut you wish to remove.

Source:
http://akuederle.com/customize-ipython-keymap/

If you want a sample `custom.js`, [this is mine](https://github.com/hlin117/dotfiles/blob/master/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js) on my github.